# Iterating Capturing Issue with Swift 2

Tags: swift

So I am attempting to use the SpriteKit update method to have a sprite's position update, which works when I use it by itself:

```
platform.positionUpdate((platform.data.velocity["x"]?.magnitude)!, deltaY: (platform.data.velocity["y"]?.magnitude)!)
```

However, when I add it to a set and iterate over that set in the same manor, it doesn't work anymore. I believe this is either due to capturing or the fact that for loops are read-only, although I'm not certain:

```
for i in physicsShapes as Set<NioShape> {
        i.positionUpdate((i.data.velocity["x"]?.magnitude)!, deltaY: (i.data.velocity["y"]?.magnitude)!)
    }
```

If anyone has a resolution to this issue, I'd really appreciate a response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by my own stupidity. Ignore this post.